# What is the main issue that I must look at in the connection string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, connection

what do I have to change in this Connection string in order to run my application locally in an other 
computer??
this is my connection string!!

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
Database=|DataDirectory|\MydataDB;
Initial Catalog=MydataDB;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integrated security means that if you run it remotely, the user account running it will also have to exist on your local computer. I would recommend creating a user/password in SQL and adding that to your connection string.

You will also have to enable the SQL services and ports that are required to allow remote connections to your database server.  You will also need to change it from .\SQLExpress to YourServerName(or IP address)\SQLExpress.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend entirely on the environment you're deploying to.  You may need to change the Data Source, Database, Initial Catalog or Integrated Security values.  Depending on the security options of the server you're deploying to you may need to add additional values as well, for example, if you're using SQL Security on the server you're deploying to.  If you have specific information about the server you're deploying to then it would be possible to provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to attach your database properly to the instance of SQL Server Express, instead of using this `|DataDirectory|` mumbo-jumbo. Then, you need to make sure SQL Server Express is set to allow remote connections, that the SQL Server Browser service is running, that TCP/IP is enabled, and that the ports aren't blocked on your firewall (make sure that you can telnet to port 1434 from the other machine). Then you need to change `.\SQLEXPRESS` to `IP or server name\SQLEXPRESS`.

```
connectionString = "Data Source=source machine name or IP\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=MydataDB;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Also, are you using `MultipleActiveResultSets` on purpose?